# how do I include a class in another file?

Tags: php

I am new to object php, I have the following concern:
    is it possible to have one class included inside another class, and use it's method like:

in Anotherclass.php file

```
  class Another
 {
    public $value = '';
    public function setValue($newvalue)
    {
      $this->value=$newvalue;
    }
    public function getValue()
    {
      return $this->value;
    }

 }
```

in Bootstrap.php  file:

```
  require(Another.inc)
  class Bootstrap
 {
    public static function main($value)
{
    $obj =  new Another();
        $obj->  setValue($value)
       echo  $obj->getValue();  

     }
 }


  Bootstrap::main("test");
```

so when I call Bootstrap::main("test") in the Bootstrap.php file, can I get the output which is "test"? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work? If not, what did not work? Was there any error message? What did it say? It did work? There is your answer.

Comment: This is (almost) valid code. What is your problem?

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/include

Comment: the guy who vote down is so anoyed and ridiculous, I am concerned about my code, so I asked, this is the website for help people solve their questions, and it's stupid if some guy think more than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a semi-colon but with that fixed it works fine :

```
$obj->  setValue($value)
```

should be

```
$obj->  setValue($value);
```

and called with `Bootstrap::main('test');` will output `test`

Working example with both classes in the same file : http://codepad.org/yHyNAoT5

I would suggest making

```
public $value = '';
```

`private`  - this forces the use of the getter and setter methods rather than accessing directly